Expecting exec.CommandContext to kill command after timeout, but that is not the case
The following code starts a sleep 30 cmd with timeout set to 5 seconds. I expect after 5 seconds for cmd to be killed by exec.CommandContext (does os.proc kill). But when i actually run this code, it takes the full duration of the actual cmd to kill.
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
defer cancel()
cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, cmdPath, CmdArgs)
fmt.Println("Starting command:", cmdPath)
startTime := time.Now()

out, err := cmd.Output()
duration := time.Since(startTime)
if err != nil {
    // Check if the error was due to a timeout
    if ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded {
        fmt.Println("command timed out: ", err, " duration: ", duration)
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Println("command err: ", err, " duration: ", duration)
    return nil, err
}
fmt.Printf("Command completed in %v\n", duration)
fmt.Println(string(out))

Output:
Starting command: sleep 50
command timed out:  context deadline exceeded  duration:  30.012089672s

The duration was not 5 seconds but rather the full 30 seconds. The cmd was timed out though because we hit the condition ctx.Err() == context.DeadlineExceeded but it should timeout after 5 seconds, not 30. Why is timeout condition not being upheld?

I am not running sleep command directly btw, i am running a script which is doing sleep 30. Running it directly does work, but my use case is calling on an external util. And i want to kill that util in the event of a timeout

Then the context is not killing the actual command you are waiting for. The signal is only going to be sent to the process started by the exec.Cmd. Can you run the command directly rather than through a script? Otherwise you need to kill all the child process too, normally done via the process group created by the shell.
